# MyCouch (CouchDB) Visual Studio Basics (Document Deletion and JSON Serialization)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, couchdb

I am trying to build a communication protocol using Visual Studio and CouchDB however, I am having issues with some pretty basic concepts and The myCouch git is far from clear.
I would like to know how to Delete a document given a database name and how to convert JSON received from the server into usable code.

Here is my C# code so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            using (var db = new MyCouch.MyCouchStore("http://UserName:Password@127.0.0.1:5984/", "patientsim"))
            {
                var json = await db.GetByIdAsync("1");
                Console.Write(json);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to delete Documents, Seriliazation still escapes me however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CouchDB documentation:

> If you want to change a document in CouchDB, you don’t tell it to go
>   and find a field in a specific document and insert a new value.
>   Instead, you load the full document out of CouchDB, make your changes
>   in the JSON structure (or object, when you are doing actual
>   programming), and save the entire new revision (or version) of that
>   document back into CouchDB. **Each revision is identified by a new _rev
>   value.**
>
> If you want to update or delete a document, CouchDB expects you to
>   include the _rev field of the revision you wish to change.

These is a way to avoid overwriting somebody else updates.

So to delete a document you first need to load it with:

```
var myDoc = await store.GetByIdAsync(docId);
```

Then you use the document Rev property to delete it:

```
var deleted = await store.DeleteAsync(docId, myDoc.Rev);
```

So it is necessary that your document model has a *Rev* property in addition to the *Id* property.

[According the documentation](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#_rev) the *Rev* property of your models could be named:

- [EntityName]Rev
- DocumentRev
- EntityRev
- Rev